# How to convert a UIImage to a CVPixelBuffer

Tags: swift, uiimage, cvpixelbuffer, coreml

Apple's new CoreML framework has a prediction function that takes a `CVPixelBuffer`. In order to classify a `UIImage` a conversion must be made between the two.

Conversion code I got from an Apple Engineer:

```
1  // image has been defined earlier
2
3     var pixelbuffer: CVPixelBuffer? = nil
4   
5     CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, Int(image.size.width), Int(image.size.height), kCVPixelFormatType_OneComponent8, nil, &pixelbuffer)
6     CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelbuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue:0))
7   
8     let colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
9     let bitmapContext = CGContext(data: CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelbuffer!), width: Int(image.size.width), height: Int(image.size.height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelbuffer!), space: colorspace, bitmapInfo: 0)!
10  
11    bitmapContext.draw(image.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))
```

This solution is in swift and is for a grayscale image. Changes that must be made depending on the type of image are:

- Line 5 | `kCVPixelFormatType_OneComponent8` to another `OSType` (`kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB` for RGB)
- Line 8 | `colorSpace` to another `CGColorSpace` (`CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB` for RGB)
- Line 9 | `bitsPerComponent` to the number of bits per pixel of memory (32 for RGB)
- Line 9 | `bitmapInfo` to a nonzero `CGBitmapInfo` property (`kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault` is the default)

Comment: I think `CVPixelBuffer` is just a convention for images from camera, there are also `ciImage`, `cgImage` available

Comment: Why not use the Vision Framework? You can (1) initialize a `VNCoreMLModel` object, then a (2) `VNCoreMLRequest` with a completion handler, then use a (3) `VNImageRequestHandler` - which can take a `CIImage` or a file URL. The results are a collection of `VNClassificationObservation` objects. Now of course, if you want to convert a `UIImage` to a `CVPixelBuffer` - which you really **didn't** say anywhere **inside** your question that didn't have a question :-) - you can simply search the internet for that and find this: https://gist.github.com/cieslak/743f9321834c5a40597afa1634a48343

Comment: @dfd Yeah so I did want to convert a `UIImage` to a `CVPixelBuffer` for the purposes of using a CoreML model, but I kindly had this problem solved by an Apple engineer at WWDC with the above code. Given that several other people at the conference have had the same problem, I figured I'd share the solution which achieves its purpose with much more simplicity than that github solution. Thanks for the suggestions though!

Comment: @Ryan: Are you asking a question or do you want to share a solution? In the latter case you should post it as a self-answered question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.

Comment: +1 to Martin R, please move the second half of your question into an answer to the question, allowing other people to answer too!

Answer (score 49):

You can take a look at this tutorial https://www.hackingwithswift.com/whats-new-in-ios-11, code is in Swift 4

```
func buffer(from image: UIImage) -> CVPixelBuffer? {
  let attrs = [kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue, kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue] as CFDictionary
  var pixelBuffer : CVPixelBuffer?
  let status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, Int(image.size.width), Int(image.size.height), kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, attrs, &pixelBuffer)
  guard (status == kCVReturnSuccess) else {
    return nil
  }

  CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
  let pixelData = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!)

  let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
  let context = CGContext(data: pixelData, width: Int(image.size.width), height: Int(image.size.height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer!), space: rgbColorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue)

  context?.translateBy(x: 0, y: image.size.height)
  context?.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

  UIGraphicsPushContext(context!)
  image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))
  UIGraphicsPopContext()
  CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

  return pixelBuffer
}
```

Comment: Would you by any chance know why the translateBy and ScaleBY are necessary ?

Comment: Oh. To move from the different coordinate systems used by UIKit and CoreGraphics. Y points down in UIKit and up in CoreGraphics ??

Comment: P.S. if you are using this buffer to do some Metal work then add ```kCVPixelBufferMetalCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue``` to `attrs`.

Comment: Same answer just as an Extension to UIImage:

Comment: Works like a charm!